# IronPython number == null?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, clr, windows-phone, ironpython

I am busy porting IronPython to Windows Phone 8 and I have now run into a problem where I cannot check if a number is null or not in a python script.

If for example I try:

```
testnum a = 0.1
if testnum == None:
    print "Value is null
```

Then I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in Microsoft.Dynamic.DLL and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: y
```

I determined that the reason this happens is because in "FEATURE_NUMERICS" is not enabled because WP does not have System.Numerics.BigInteger and System.Numerics.Complex. In the current source it seems that those two were then manually implemented.

I have changed all the "==" opertors in the BigInterger implementation to support null like the example below:

```
public static bool operator ==(BigInteger x, BigInteger y) {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;
        return Compare(x, y) == 0;
    }
```

I have though realized that this is actually quite useless because y will never be any form of a number which contains a null value. The reason for this is because (I am assuming) IPY parses the python script and decides which type of value to apply operations on and when it sees a number and a null automatically throws a 'System.ArgumentNullException' therefor never even sending it to BigInterger.

My problem now is that I have no idea where this exception originated, I am assuming somewhere in the parser. My idea is to when I find the origin do something like I did above where I simply return false. Do any of you have any idea where I should look for the place where this exception originated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working, the problem was indeed with the integer module, I just wasn't looking wide enough.